# Time-consuming task in MainForm, progress bar in another form

Tags: c#, multithreading, modal-dialog, progress-bar, progressdialog

I have a main UI that doing some time-consuming work. When it is executing, I would like to open a second form with a progress bar (marquee style) to indicate "working on it".

I have seen people putting the time-consuming task in the `BackgroundWorker`, however, **I would like to run in the main UI thread**.

The time-consuming task will be executed in `MainForm`. I would like to reuse the progress bar for various process, so I am writing a second form `ProgressBarForm` with `BackgroundWorker` in it, that would start the `_mainWork` at the same time as showing progress bar, and will stop and close the `ProgressBarForm` when `_mainWork` is done.

Because forms are modals, I am thinking of showing `ProgressBarForm` in the `BackgroundWorker` in order not to block `MainForm`.

Please note that I am **not** running `mainForm` in `BackgroundWorker`. My backgroundWorker just show the form and perhaps report a timer.

```
public partial class ProgressBarFom : UControl
{
    public delegate void MainWork();
    private MainWork _mainWork;
    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //progressBar.Hide();
        this.OnClose(sender, e);
        //
        backgroundWorker.Dispose();
    }
        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //show this ProgressBarForm
            this.ShowDialog();
            //stop backgroundWorker
            //calling this.Close() in RunWorkerComplete 

            if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        public void CallProgressBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //progressBar.Show();
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

            _mainWork();
            if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
                backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
        }
}
```

In MainForm, I am passing mainwork and call ExecWithProgressBar

```
private void ExecWithProgressBar()
    {
        ProgressBarFom .MainWork mainWork = new ProgressBarFom .MainWork(ProgressBarMainWork);
        ProgressBarFom prBar = new ProgressBarFom (mainWork);
        prBar.CallProgressBar(null, null);
    }
```

Some problems I encoutered

1. Inside DoWork, the same modal issue occurs. ShowDialog() will block the thread  and therefore I never get to check CancellationPending to close ProgressBarForm.
2. ProgressBarForm starts later then the mainWork. I thought when I called  CallProgressBar, the backgroundWorker should start well before my mainWork.
3. Is worker.Dispose() necessary in RunWorkerComplete?
4. Would it be a better choice to run mainWork in Worker? And why? I decided to let the main thread run this to not disturb the normal flow, what in Main thread will remain in Main thread, Progress bar is like an addon. If we bring it to the worker, would we need another thread to for progress bar itself?

Comment: _"I have seen people putting the time-consuming task in the BackgroundWorker, however, I would like to run in the main UI thread"_ -- why? Why do you want to reject the good advice of experienced programmers and intended design of the .NET API? Just do it the right way. Not only are there way better resources to explain to you how to do it the right way, your program will simply work better. Fighting an API is a sure-fire way to give you plenty of headaches and really crappy code.

Comment: I tried putting _mainWork in backgroundWorker, which posed problems. I guessed it is because _mainWork uses something from the main thread. How would you suggest overcoming this?

Comment: `BackgroundWorker`, and its successor `Task` and `Progress<T>`, are no panacea. You can still do it wrong and make mistakes. But the thing is: there are _lots_ of online resources to help people who are doing it wrong and making mistakes learn how to do it right and without mistakes. There are very few online resources designed to help people succeed at doing it wrong, and very little incentive for anyone to put effort into creating such resources. If you have problems getting `BackgroundWorker` to work, ask for help doing it right. Your current approach is doomed.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I did do some homework, unfortunately examples and tutorials online tend to stop at "//Simulate some time-consuming task: DoWork{System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);}" Could you elaborate how to invoke _mainwork in backgroundworker properly? Will it defeat the purpose that I am using worker thread but in turn asking main thread to do the job? I would wish to have this progress bar form reusable, something that run along with any methods that I feed in. That's why I attempted to feed in _mainWork to the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: _"Will it defeat the purpost that I am using worker thread but in turn asking main thread to do the job"_ -- yes. _"I would wish to have this progress bar form reusable"_ -- just as the `ProgressBar` control is reusable, so too can any other progress UI implementation be. As far as elaborating on _"how to invoke _mainwork in backgroundworker"_, it will work better if you make an attempt, then post a question in which you explain that attempt as well as describe what documentation and tutorials you've used, and ask for help with that attempt. Otherwise, an answer becomes too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do some very ugly hacks (like running more than one message loop inside your application) you cannot display a dialog if the thread running the main window is busy. All dialogs use the same thread to do the display update stuff in WinForms. In fact, they even *must* be running on the same thread.

There's one (sometimes acceptable) hack using `Application.DoEvents()`, but I wouldn't use it either, because it gets you into a lot of problems as well.

So the simple answer is: This doesn't work. Use a background worker to do lengthy processing.

Comment: I probably would not have mentioned `Application.DoEvents()` (even with a warning) as it is advertising an arguably bad API method that novices should best be kept ignorant of. :)

Comment: @MickyDuncan: Not sure... I wouldn't let novices find out all the pitfalls of their own. I did have a very bad time getting rid of it in my code :-/

Comment: Actually, any STA thread can display UI, dialog or otherwise. The actual `BackgroundWorker` thread can't be an STA thread (it's a thread pool thread and .NET doesn't give control over its initialization), but it's not true that "all dialogs use the same thread", nor that they "must be running on the same thread". **Not that I would recommend more than one UI thread per process**. Just that it's not factually correct to state there cannot be more than one UI thread per process.

Comment: I attempted to use background worker to do the lengthy work. Yet this results in many exceptions, perhaps because the method use APIs and methods from the main thread.

Comment: @Kenny: Are you attempting to update the UI from your background thread (i.e. setting control properties)? If so, you must use `Invoke()`.

Comment: Note that when using `BackgroundWorker` or the newer `Task` idioms, `Invoke()` is generally not necessary, as `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` or `Progress<T>.ProgressChanged` provides the mechanism for information in the background task flowing back to the UI.

Comment: @PMF: I am not trying to update the UI from my background's ProgressChanged. I would like to execute another method supposedly in the main thread, while having the progress bar form run in parallel, to show that the method is active. I would want this progress bar to be reusable, so that I can hook it with any lengthy method in the main thread.